# Exempt users with the association bonus from the IP-based question rate limit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, rate-limiting

I've just created an account on Cross Validated, and typed up my first question.

Unfortunately, when I try to submit it, I get an *You can only post once every 40 minutes* error message.

I've never posted a question on Cross Validated before, and do have the association bonus. I've also not posted a question on any other site today. My IP address is probably shared with users that post more frequently, though. Some of those users may have 125+ rep and thus not be subject to the rate limit on their own account, but do end up restricting other users posting from the same IP. Thus, the limit is probably because of IP-based rate limiting.

Could we restrict IP-based rate limiting to users that haven't received the association bonus?

Users that are eligible for the association bonus are clearly not just creating accounts to circumvent rate limits, and can more easily be moderated since they can be suspended network-wide and that will also affect any new account that they create.

The current implementation likely hurts several people, such as employees at large companies or students at large universities.

Comment: Did you by any chance ask a question on some other site in the last 40 minutes, including a site where you have 125 reputation and thus not subject to the limit there?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog No, besides this question I haven't asked others today. I have got my question submitted on Cross Validated by just trying, though, but it's not a good user experience to just try and submit every few minutes.

Comment: There are a few people who have the association bonus and still hit the rate-limit. I've seen post-ban questions on the local meta of a site I'm active on.

Comment: @Chair I'm not advocating removing the entire rate limit, just the IP-based one (that prevents people from creating new accounts to bypass the rate limit). They would still be unable to do that, since if they would create a new account, they would not have the association bonus.